# Giving an initial velocity to an object at the start of an animation

Tags: animation, objects

In my animation, I want to start with an animated object that has an initial velocity. From frame 1 and so on, this velocity is then supposed to evolve according to the physics simulation (i.e gravity). For this reason, I think keyframes aren't the solution, but I may be wrong.

Edit : in fact, I was wrong and that's why I accepted the answer, but probably only if the object is a rigid body. I haven't been able to find an animated checkbox for an object which is a soft body.

Is it possible to do this and how?

Comment: hello, could you please elaborate a bit? To set the acceleration you can go into the Graph Editor and tweak the vertices handles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select object on frame 1

Insert keyframe (L) -> Location

Insert keyframe on animated-checkbox (checked)

Choose frame 2 on timeline

Move your object, (the more you move, the more acceleration it will have)

Insert keyframe(L) -> Location

Choose frame 3 on timeline

Insert keyframe on animated-checkbox (unchecked)

Comment: Just to be clear, this gives an object an initial **velocity**, not acceleration, though that's probably what the OP wanted.

Comment: yes, you  are right, i hope he meant that ;)